# Write two char Arrays in an other char array dont work

Tags: c, char, arrays

Output: "Hello"
Why the output isnt "Hello World"?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char x[] = "Hello", y[]="World",  xy[50];
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; x[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        xy[i] = x[i];
    }
    i++;
    xy[i] = ' ';
    for(j=0; y[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            i++;
        xy[i] = y[j];
    }
    printf("%s", xy);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `xy[50] = "12345_"`; experiment with different characters at the `_` position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is right here:

```
    i++;
    xy[i] = ' ';
```

You skip over one character of `xy`, leaving it uninitialized.

To fix, remove the `i++`:

```
    xy[i] = ' ';
```

Another problem is that you don't append a NUL character at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you increment `i` before setting `xy[i] = ' '`. This leaves `xy[i]` set to a potentially incorrect value. Use `xy[i++] = ' ';` instead, and in general, pay attention to the order of your increments: there are more places in your program where you got it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried single stepping through your code?If not try it.You will realize you have left a random character in xy when you did

```
      i++; //line 10
```

at line 10.On good days it will be a null character.So you just see a null.On bad days it can be any weird char so you may end up even getting **Hello!World**